# Series representation of an expression?

Tags: power-series

What is the series representation of $(1+x)^{-n}$, where $n$ is a positive integer?
I have this term in an integral, and I want to replace this term by a series representation to be able to solve the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You may also recall the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*
>   \begin{align*}
> (1+x)^{-n}&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{-n}{k}x^k\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{n+k-1}{k}(-1)^kx^k
> \end{align*}

In (1) we use a *[binomial identity with negative integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_negative_integers)*.

Since the definition of a binomial coefficient with general $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is
\begin{align*}
\binom{\alpha}{k}=\frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)(\alpha-2)\cdots(\alpha-(k-1))}{k!}
\end{align*}
we obtain
\begin{align*}
\binom{-n}{k}&=\frac{-n(-n-1)(-n-2)\cdots(-n-(k-1))}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(n+(k-1))}{k!}\\
&=(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}
\end{align*}

Comment: i reached (1), but i couldn't complete because of the negative sign in (n)

Comment: @user42138: Derivation added (see also the referred link).

Comment: great, thank you so much.

Comment: @user42138: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Recall that
$$\frac1{1+x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k x^k$$

Now take $(n-1)$ derivatives on both sides.

Comment: (n-1) derivatives? can you show me how this may be done?? Thank you a lot. @J.R.

Comment: Well take the first derivative then you get

Comment: $-1/(1+x)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k k x^{k-1}$ .. etc.

Comment: Second derivative, $2/(1+x)^3 = \sum_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k k(k-1) x^{k-2}$.. can you come up with a pattern and write down the $(n-1)$th derivative?

Comment: oh i see, is there a general formula for the (n-1) derivatives, and i have a question; why (n-1)? why not n? @J.R.

Comment: Because the $(n-1)$th derivative of $1/(1+x)$ is what you want: constant times $1/(1+x)^n$. The $n$th derivative would leave us with constant times $1/(1+x)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Now you do the rest (i.e. come up with the formula for $n-1$). It's a good exercise, trust me.

Comment: i see, ok i'll do it, after i get a general pattern, is this will be the expansion to my term? @J.R.

Comment: Yes. Then, you will also be able to simplify it and on the right hand side there should appear a certain [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) after simplification.

Comment: great. i'll do it now, thank you so much.@J.R.

Comment: done. i got: $\frac{(n-1)! (-1)^{n-1}}{(1+x)^n}=\sum_{k=n-1}(-1)^k \prod_{r=0}^{n-2}(k-r) x^{k-(n-1)}$ @J.R.

Comment: Correct. Now simplify.

Comment: I couldn't simplify it more...what can i do more?

Comment: Put constants on right hand side and index shift in the summation.

Comment: i got this : $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{ (-1)^k{{k+n-1}\choose {n-1}} x^k}$, is it right??